# Why is this replace method not working properly

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a file that has data that looks something like this:

```
1 1:-0.03125 2:0.236364 3:0.142857 4:-0.107438 5:0.129032 6:0.163636 7:0.242105
2 1:-0.03125 2:0.472727 3:0.761905 4:0.123967 6:0.472727 7:0.347368
....
```

Where there are a couple thousand lines total. I am trying to convert this over to a csv file.

I tried the following code:

```
with open("file1.test", "r") as infile:
    with open("file1.csv", "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            new_line = line
            i = 1
            for i in range(1,8):
                to_replace = " " + str(i) + ":"
                new_line = new_line.replace(to_replace, ",", 1)
            new_line = line[:2] + "," + line[2:]
            new_line = new_line.replace(" ", "", 1)
```

But it does not work as expected. The line `new_line = new_line.replace(" ", "", 1)` works but when I am trying to replace the " 1:" with a comma it does not update. I want my final file to look like"

```
1, -0.03125,0.236364,0.142857,-0.107438,0.129032,0.163636,0.242105
2,-0.03125,0.472727,0.761905,0.123967,0.472727,0.347368
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `.replace()`s probably all worked just fine.  However, you threw away all that work with the statement `new_line = line[:2] + "," + line[2:]`, which uses only the original value of `line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this conversion approach for every line:

```
>>> a = '1 1:-0.03125 2:0.236364 3:0.142857 4:-0.107438 5:0.129032 6:0.163636 7:0.242105'
>>> ','.join( [i.split(':')[-1] for i in a.split()] )
'1,-0.03125,0.236364,0.142857,-0.107438,0.129032,0.163636,0.242105'
```

with your whole program looking like this:

```
with open("file1.test", "r") as infile:
    text = [i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()]

output = []
for t in text :
    output.append( ','.join( [i.split(':')[-1] for i in t.split()] ) )

with open("file1.csv", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write( '\n'.join( output ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this

```
import re  
with open("file1.test", "r") as infile:
    with open("file1.csv", "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(re.sub(' [1-7]:',',',line))
```